# F# Finding occurrences of value in list

Tags: f#

I'm quite a newbie at F# and want to find how many times a value `x` has occurred in a list `ys`

So for example `multiplicity (2, [1;2;3;4;2])` returns 2. The code I've written below returns 4 on the above example. What am I missing?

```
let rec multiplicity (x, ys) =
match ys with
| []                -> 0
| y::tail when x=y  -> x + multiplicity(x, tail)
| y::tail           -> multiplicity(x, tail)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, this is a good example of why it's always a good idea to write down a problem/question.

I figured out, I should do this instead:

```
let rec multiplicity (x, ys) =
match ys with
| []                -> 0
| y::tail when x=y  -> 1 + multiplicity(x, tail)
| y::tail           -> multiplicity(x, tail)
```

It should be `1` and not `x`, which is added to the recursive call, doh.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not writing this as a recursive function as a learning exercise, it's probably more idiomatic to use the built-in collection functions:

```
[1;2;3;4;2] |> Seq.filter ((=) 2) |> Seq.length

[1;2;3;4;2] |> List.sumBy (fun x -> if x = 2 then 1 else 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and you are probably correct. It's mostly to get some intuition for recursion and pattern matching that I chose the long way around.

Answer (score 0):

I find it's a good idea to replace recursion with fold, so here is another version:

```
let xs = [1;2;3;4;2]
(0,xs) ||> List.fold (fun acc elem -> match elem with 
                                        | 2 -> acc + 1
                                        | _ -> acc)
```

You can also use `countBy`, which will return a list of tuples with true and false.

```
xs |> List.countBy (fun x -> x = 2)
```